# Plasma frequency in relativistic case

Tags: special-relativity, frequency, plasma-physics

The non-relativistic plasma frequency definition is $$ \omega_p = \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi n e^2}{m}}, $$ where $n$ is the density, $e$ is the electron charge, and $m$ is the mass of the species that we consider.

In the relativistic case, it is used another expression of the above, namely
$$ \omega_p = \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi n e^2}{m}} \left(1+ \frac{\theta}{\chi -1} \right)^{-1/2}, $$
where $\theta = k_B T / mc^2$ is the dimensionless temperature, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ the temperature of the plasma, $c$ is the speed of light, and$\chi$ is the adiabatic index.
The latter definition, clearly, depends on the (relativistic) temperature of the plasma, and this make sense because kinetic effects of particles become relevant in the relativistic limit.

I have searched but have not found the way to derive the second one from the first one. Someone can please suggest me where can I find this? (Books or papers).

Comment: I suggest that you outline in your question the method that you use to obtain the plasma frequency in non-relativistic case. Also, you might be confusing the situations that apply to ["cold" and "warm" plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation)